# Vue не принимает данные

Tags: laravel, vue.js

в контроллере отдаю данные вот так

```
public function listOffers(){
    return Offer::all()->toJson();
}
```

роут

```
Route::get('/offers/list','OffersController@listOffers')->name('offersList');
```

сам компонент , но выдает в консоле undefined

```
<template>
        <div class="offers">
            <div class="offer" v-for="offeri in listoffers">
                <img src="img/com-user.png" alt="" class="avatar">
                <div class="data-offer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="/offers/" class="text">{{offeri.title}}</a>
                        <p class="fullname">nadinak [Nadinak]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="data-offer-meta">
                        <span class="date">09.03.2019г. 15:15</span>
                        <div class="data-action">
                            <p class="up">
                                <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                                <span>1</span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="down">
                                <svg class="up"><use xlink:href="#up"></use></svg>
                                <span>1</span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="comments">
                                <svg class="comment"><use xlink:href="#comment"></use></svg>
                                <span>0</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data: function(){
              return {
                  listoffers: []
              }
            },
            mounted() {
                this.update()
            },
            methods: {
                update: function () {

                    axios.get('/offers/list').then((response) => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                        this.listoffers = response.data
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Если `console.log(response.data)` выдает `undefined`, to почему бы не проверить `console.log(response)`?

Comment: а еще лучше, заглянуть в Network